# new Date() vs. Utilities.formatDate(new Date())

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script, format, utilities

Can anyone tell me why this code would produce two different dates?

```
let now = new Date();  // today's date (1/2/2021)
Logger.log(now);       // Sat Jan 02 09:42:47 GMT-08:00 2021
Logger.log(new Date(now.getTime()-(2*1000*60*60*24)));   // Thu Dec 31 09:42:47 GMT-08:00 2020
Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(now.getTime()-(2*1000*60*60*24)), "GMT-8", "MM/d/YYYY"));  // 12/31/2021
```

Why would `Utilities.formateDate()` change the date from **12/31/2020** to **12/31/2021**?

******** SOLUTION *********

Change the date format from `"MM/d/YYYY"` to `"MM/d/yyyy"`.

Comment: what is `Utilities`? PS: ah, seems to be a google apps script specific tool. I've added that tag to clarify.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28956532/google-apps-script-date-format-issue-utilities-formatdate

Comment: check also the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51904670/google-script-formatdate-off-by-1-year-when-input-date-is-dec-30-or-31) one.

Comment: Yes,  Utilities.formatDate() is a google apps script tool.  Good catch & thanks for adding the tag.

Comment: ... also, changing the format from ```"MM/d/YYYY"``` to ```"MM/d/yyyy"``` solved the issue.  Many thanks to all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a simple formatting problem.  [Look here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

This:
`Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(now.getTime()-(2*1000*60*60*24)), "GMT-8", "MM/d/YYYY"));`

Should be this:

`Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(now.getTime()-(2*1000*60*60*24)), "GMT-8", "MM/d/yyyy"));`

In other words just make the capital Y's lower case y's and you're there.